# Finding a string within a block of code (regexp)

Tags: regex, linux, string, grep, newline

I need to find the name of the files that contain a string within a block of code (which can of course contain newlines), or more specifically: certain method call inside a constructor (let's call it **methodName**). I need to look in all java code files in the current directory and its subdirs.

A possible match would be:

```
public myClass() {
  a(1);
  b();
  myMethod("abc");
  c(5);
}
```

This is the expression I've come up with so far:

```
find . -name *.java | xargs nawk '{print $0 "~("FILENAME")"}' | tr -d "\n" | grep -s -i -o 'public \w\+([^)]*).*methodName([^~]*~([^)]*)'
```

So...
- *.java files are found recursively
- each line is printed out and next to it the file name it belongs to (just to keep track where it was found)
- The \n are removed to be able to use grep in a block
- then **methodName** is looked for.

The problem is that every time I need to use .* I have to change the expression to a negation of the next expression and then the next expression. E.g.: if I need `.*\~`, I need to do `([^~]*~`... That not nice, but I can live with it. The problem comes with **methodName**, because negating that string is gonna be more painful.

Any ideas? Can it be done with a regexp?

Comment: Am I really stupid or does it look like the `tr -d "\n"` will essentially print *everything* in one big line?

Comment: @ArjunShankar I guess that is what he wants to do. since the "public ... methodname.." could contain line breaks in original file. however, I didn't really understand what OP is gonna search. OP: can you just make it simpler, e.g. I want to search "something" in all java files. can you define "something" ?

Comment: If you search for `.*methodName` then grep will not just eat up `methodName` by matching it to the `.*`. Grep likes to find a match, and it will.

Answer (score 1):

You're struggling with greediness. `.*` is going greedy by default, so it's going to consume as much as it can, being everything.  Only after it cosumes everything will it try to match the next part of your expression `m` and backtrack until it does.  If it does find the rest of the pattern it will match everything from the first occurence of the pattern in front of the `.*` ('public \w+([^)]*)') to the last occurence of the pattern behind the `.*` (`methodName([^~]*~([^)]*)`).

The solution is to make the `.*` lazy: `.*?`, giving you the full expression `public \w\+([^)]*).*?methodName([^~]*~([^)]*)`

Interestingly, your workaround of using the negated character classes is the preferred solution in the cases you used it, but, yes, doing something similar with `methodName` can become a bit unwieldy.

See: [Laziness Instead of Greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of grep, try using sed.  Here is something that might help you get started:

```
find . -name *.java | xargs awk '{print $0 "~("FILENAME")"}' | \
sed -n '                                  # start sed with automatic printing suppressed
/public \w\+/,/^}/H                       # append all constructors to hold space
$!d                                       # stop here unless this is the last line
g                                         # copy hold space to pattern space
s/.*methodName([^~]*~(\([^)]*\)).*/\1/p   # if methodName is called, print the file name
'
```